# read json request node js in router script

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, body-parser

hello everyone i have tried many ways to get the body of request from postman into my scripts but always the body is empty can you maybe help me out to get it right

i have created the server in index.js and when i try to read the request body from it work fine
here is an Example
[this is the index script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/235RF.jpg)

```
const express =require('express');
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const app=express();
require('dotenv').config();
const ConnectDB=require("./config/db");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));

ConnectDB()

app.use('/api/users',require('./routes/usersRouter.js'))

app.post('/test',(req,res)=>{
res.json(req.body)
})

const port=process.env.PORT||3000;
app.listen(port,()=>console.log("server start on "+port));
```

input in postman
[in-output postman index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVtHR.jpg)

```
const express =require('express');
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const router =express.Router();

router.use(express.json());
router.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));

 //signup Route
 router.get('/signup',(req , res) => {

    console.log(req.body);

  });

module.exports=router;
```

and here is my Router script inside it i can't read the body of request i have tried many different ways but didn't workout
[usersRouter js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3sNJ.jpg)

[in-output postmna userRouter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cOO3.jpg)

Comment: While pictures can be worth a thousand words, this is not true for code. Please post the actual code in your question, not pictures of it

Comment: it's just in postman didn't work in insomnia work fine

Answer (score 0):

your code is correctly, your problem is about postman because your req.headers in not complate like this :

```
{
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.26.8',
  accept: '*/*',
  'postman-token': '06924678-2c5e-4e14-93da-50a16ca06c20',
  host: '127.0.0.1:6060',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '28'
}
```

please  uninstall and re-install postman, but some issue there are in your code,
delete this lines from router.js,
when you have a data in `req.body` use `post` request

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
router.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: You should not use body parser in router

Comment: ya i have tried but it is the same issue i get it empty

Comment: your code is correctly, check another things, I tested your code, and code in pictures different is with code added to the question, singup is get request or post request?? updated your express

Answer (score 0):

try this in the same order as mine

```js
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
```

and also convert the request method on `/signup` to `post`, because when you make a request for signup you post your details not get

```js
 router.post('/signup',(req , res) => {

    console.log(req.body);

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

for express to process the `body`, you need to specify `router.post('/signup', ...)` rather than `get`. If you have both `get` and `post` requests you handle from the same route, you can use `router.all('/signup', ...)`.
More information can be found in the [docs of express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using express 4? It's built-in express 4. So, app.use(express.json()) in first file should be works correctly. App.use means you are registering middleware to read json body request, it just need declare once and on your route file, you don't need to to use it again. You can try change your userRoute.js like this :

```
const express =require('express');
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const router =express.Router();

// i think you don't need this
// router.use(express.json());
// router.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));

 //signup Route
 router.get('/signup',(req , res) => {

    console.log(req.body);

  });
// change this line below
// module.exports=router;
// to
export default router;
```